# Entire list of the available MIPS32 instructions

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am looking for  entire list of the available MIPS32 instructions, system calls, and assembler directives. (Found such several partial lists)
Is it possible to dump such list from mars - simulator or any other source

Comment: See _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_

Answer (score 0):

If you have MARS4_5.jar, then since that includes sources and documentation materials — open the jar file with 7-zip or other to view them.

Alternatively, the same code has been copied here: https://github.com/MoralCode/MARS-MIPS

So, you can glean anything you need from a serious study of that.  There are documents to read, and source code, too.

There's no reason to believe that MARS simulates each and every instruction of MIPS32 — their documentation says "MARS assembles and simulates 155 basic instructions of the MIPS-32 instruction set, approximately 370 pseudo-instructions or instruction variations, the 17 syscall functions mainly for console and file I/O defined by SPIM, and an additional 22 syscalls" ...

Specifically, the MARS documentation refers to basic instructions, and that probably means that some privileged instructions and/or other rarely used features of the ISA have been omitted.

(There's also no particular reason to believe that MARS is a pure subset of MIPS32, meaning that though they don't claim so, they may have added additional features not supported by the MIPS32 specification.)

Otherwise, independent of MARS, the MIPS32 architecture is fairly well documented & available online.

Comment: Most notably, MARS supports the "no branch delay slots" nonstandard ISA extension.